# Cant import table to H2O, using Postgresql JDBC in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, jdbc, h2o

I am having trouble to import a sql table to `H2O.ai` using Postgresql JDBC Driver in Ubuntu. I'm getting the follow error:

ERROR MESSAGE:

> SQLException: ERROR: relation "XXX" does not exist
>     Position: 22
>   Failed to connect and read from SQL database with connection_url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/...**

I am executing H2O with the follow command:

```
java -cp h2o.jar:/usr/share/java/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar water.H2OApp
```

The JDBC driver is installed and already try to construct the Connection URL in several ways.

I'm using this one right now:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/XXX?&useSSL=false
```

Comment: hi @AleGoTo can you let us know what version of H2O-3 you are using and which api you are using (i.e. python, R, Flow). Here is the corresponding user guide page: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html

Comment: Hello! I am using h2o-3.20.0.10 and Python API. I already check that documentation but cant find anything that make it work.

Comment: Is "XXX" an existing database? The format to connect to postgresql is described here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html 

The error message you are getting indicates the XXX database doesn't exist. 

Please also include the specific Python command you are using to read the table.

Comment: Yes, XXX it's an existing DB. I am testing the connection via the H2O interface in executed in the browser (http://localhost:54321). Then i set the parameters for importSqlTable.

Comment: Can you please provide the H2O logs? Did you try connecting to the database using a 3rd party tool that uses JDBC? Something like http://software.clapper.org/sqlshell/